# How to use phonegap plugins in intel XDK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I was developing an android app, using intel XDK. I was wondering if there was anyway i could incorporate PhoneGap plugins into my code, for their usage.
I have noticed that the usage of PhoneGap plugins is not the same as using Jquery plugins. A little help here would be suggested.
The code for the app is written in HTML, CSS, JS and JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to documentation for adding Cordova plugins in Intel XDK project:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/adding-third-party-plugins-to-your-xdk-cordova-app

Go to Project Settings -> Plugins -> third-party plugins -> add plugin details